# Getting battery remaining percentages programmatically in windows phone 7 Application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

How to get remaining battery percentage in windows phone 7 Application?
I have tried Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue() but it is not working.

Comment: As far as I know: Not possible

Comment: Indeed. An API has been added on Windows Phone 8, but there's no way to do that on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thnx for your replay.I also found that there is no way of doing this in windows phone 7 though it is now available on 8.

Comment: @KooKiz Thnx for your replay.I also found that there is no way of doing this in windows phone 7 though it is now available on 8.